# changes made in app.js file in react native project are not reflecting

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a React Native Project in windows system and able to launch the app on android device using react-native run-android.
But when i edit the app.js file, the changes are not reflected in the mobile app.
it always showing the below default text.
Welcome to React Native!
To get started, edit App.js
Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,Shake or press menu button for dev menu.
How to resolve the above issue.

Comment: If you close the app and run again `react-native run-android` did you see your changes ?

Comment: Some times it ma occur cache, but it accept its is a first step, But you need to do things

1. react-native start --reset-cache

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to enable `hot reloading` and `live reloading` from the developer menu, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on Mac while your focus is the virtual device. Details [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging)